# Spring Security - How to check user has access to his own resources?

Tags: spring-security, authorization

In Spring Security we can have roles but this is not sufficient for my case. For example if User A log in he can't view/change User B's data and both users will have same role like ROLE_USER. Is there any built in mechanism for this in Spring Security ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add method level security in that you check if that user with `ROLE_USER` can access particular resource with help some expression as [given here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#method-security-expressions)
And configuration can be done as [given here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-method)